# How to change Proxy Server by code

Tags: c#, proxy

To change Proxy server I have to go to IE->Internet Options->LAN Settings and click on "Use a proxy server for your LAN".  I am sure there is some way of doing that by code.  Does anybody has any idea how to do it (C#)?

Thanks a lot.

Sincerely,
Vlad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you were to make a batch file, and then create a shortcut to it on your desktop, and then hotlink to it with something like ctrl+alt+n

And the batch looked like this:

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings]
"ProxyEnable"=dword:00000001
"ProxyServer"="10.22.40.6:3128"

Comment: Thanks a lot.  That is it.  I did not know that setting is in registry.  I can write any code to change that flag.

Vlad.

Comment: Glad I could be of help.  Take care

Answer (score 0):

If you want to setup the proxy for use by your code you can set it via the [GlobalProxySelection.Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.globalproxyselection.select.aspx) property.

However Microsoft does not recommend setting the proxy manually and recommends always using the default proxy.